# How to select the row with highest value from the result of an existing query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL query that returns a list of results. The sql is :

```
SELECT fcategory,sum(fquantity*fprice) AS qty FROM items GROUP BY fcategory
```

The output is something like

```
----------------
category|qty
----------------
   a    | 10
   b    | 100
   c    | 554
```

Based on the result of the sql statement above, how do I retrieve the row with maximum quantity? (in this case I want the query to return just "c" )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add order by + limit 1 to get this :

```
SELECT fcategory,sum(fquantity*fprice) AS qty FROM items GROUP BY fcategory 
order by qty desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the highest qty, just get the first result ordered by qty like:

```
SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY qty desc limit 1
```

In your own case,

```
SELECT fcategory,sum(fquantity*fprice) AS qty FROM items GROUP BY fcategory ORDER BY qty LIMIT 1
```